# $X$ sequentally Compact implies that $X$ is complete

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

I was reading through Roydens book and there is one part that I don't understand. Here is the proof.

Suppose $X$ is **sequentially compact** metric space, then
 $$X \text{ is sequentally compact}:= \{x_n\} \subset X \Rightarrow \exists\{x_{n_k}\} \subset \{x_n\}: \{x_{n_k}\} \to x\in X.$$
Assume that $\{x_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence, then there exists a subsequence $\{x_{n_k}\}$ that converges to a point in $X$. Then, using the properties of Cauchy Sequence, it's not hard to show that the whole sequence converges.

But I don't wee why and what properties has Cauchy Sequences in order for the whole sequence to converges. I am not getting the last part.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you mean a metric space $(X,d)$: If $x_{n_k} \to x$ then 
$$
 d(x_n,x) \leq d(x_n,x_{n_k}) + d(x_{n_k},x) 
$$
The first term can be made small by using the Cauchy property. The second term gets small by convergence of the subsequence.